# Stackoverflow error in struts2

Tags: java, struts2

I am getting the below stack overflow error in my web application. This issue is coming only in production environment and that too intermittently. Once we restart the tomcat application works fine.

```
Exception initializing page context
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:216)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:547)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:216)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:547)
```

Below error keeps on repeating itself.
Any suggestions on this will be very helpful

Comment: Post whole stacktrace. When exactly are you getting this exception?

Comment: Hopefully it's obvious there isn't enough information anybody could use to help.